# Why do IDocs have different number of segments?

Tags: idoc

I am new to IDocs and I am still exploring.
Just want to know why do IDocs have different number of segments?
For example: In WE02, I have this Outbound IDoc number 0001 and it has 324 segments, while IDoc number 0002 only has 26 segments.

I know that we are assigning segments to IDocs, but why is it there are different number of segments? I don't get the segment assignment. Can anyone share related link to this? or explain..

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Which Idoc type do you have? Outgoing Idocs may be an order confirmation. Depending on the size of the order (item lines in the order) you have different numbers of segments (each item line has its own segments).

Answer (score 1):

IDoc segments differ because IDocs can be of different [types](http://www.edibasics.com/edi-resources/document-standards/sap/) where one type has more segments than another.

> I know that we are assigning segments to idocs

You can [define](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/dc/6b828943d711d1893e0000e8323c4f/content.htm) only extension IDoc types, while basic types cannot be changed.

Your should read more about IDocs, for example [here](http://www.guru99.com/all-about-idocdefinition-architecture-implementation.html).